# Detecting both Click and Touch for an ImageView on android

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I have an ImageView called **fullImage**. 
I have to detect both Touch and Click on it.

The problem is that **setOnClickListener** is not working if **setOnTouchListener** is also set for the same ImageView.

> the onTouch code

```
fullImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getBaseContext()) {
    @Override
    public void onSwipeLeft() {

    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {

    }

});
```

> the onClick code

```
fullImage.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d("click status", "click received");

            }
        });
```

Any pointers on how to solve ?

Comment: Is OnSwipeTouchListener is custom that you have created?

Comment: yes. onSwipeLeft() and onSwipeRight() are custom code. on the same image view I want swipe right and left functionality plus click. onSwipeLeft() and onSwipeRight() are working fine. Just that onClick is not working if onTouch is there.

Comment: Ok. Try this pass the view also in onTouchListener using that you can check for action, in action up you can do your work it will work same as click.

Comment: Couldn't understand you. How the code should be like ?

Comment: check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}


@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e("Touch up", "Touch up");
        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
            if (distanceX > 0)
                onSwipeRight();
            else
                onSwipeLeft();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: not working. click not detecting. but swipe detecting.

Comment: Can you add the code of your custom touch listener?

Comment: Great. See there is onDown method there should be something related to onUp if not than created it usint the motion event. By this you can work. Let me know if you are not able to to do that I will help you after sometime now.

Comment: I'm trying hard. But unable to write a 'Up' method for it. Can you suggest any custom code/ library to detect left/right swipe and touch/click both on a single view ??

Comment: Ok let me look into that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91920/discussion-between-hardik-chauhan-and-gissipi-453).

Comment: I have updated ur custom listener to found the touch up event.
See the updated ans.